# Where is linux-tick-processor on node.js ubuntu native package installation?

Tags: node.js

I have installed Node.js on an Ubuntu 64bit server using a standard apt-get and would like to profile scripts through the "--prof" flag.
Web searching shows there should be a tool to process the v8.log output located in "deps/v8/tools/linux-tick-processor" but I don't seem to have any of those directories. Do they come with the native install? should they be installed separately? if so how?
Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You need to download the source package with `sudo apt-get source nodejs`.The path you mentioned is in there.

You'll need to `scons prof=on d8` in deps/v8 to build the debugger first, which might have some trouble on a 64-bit machine (v8 is 32-bit only), see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85978/building-a-32-bit-app-in-64-bit-ubuntu) for more info.

Comment: V8 no longer uses scons

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I did it for Node.js 0.10.25 and 0.10.26:

1. I downloaded the source for Node.js that corresponds to the binaries I'm using. (I'm on Debian testing, which is a bit behind the releases from the Node.js web site.)
2. I checked the version of v8 bundled in the node sources. (Look at `deps/v8/ChangeLog`. It was 3.14.5 for Node.js 0.10.25 and 0.10.26.)
3. I downloaded this **exact** version of v8 from the [v8 site](http://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/Source?tm=4).

   Why? I tried running `make native` in Node.js `deps/v8` directory but the `Makefile` was complaining about a missing test directory. From this we can infer that the Node developers are not including the entire v8 distribution. Once upon a time, with an earlier version of Node (0.8.something) I did build v8 from what was available in `deps/v8` but this time I decided to use a different approach.
4. As explained in v8's `build/README.txt`, in the top level of the source tree for v8, I did:

   ```
   $ svn co http://gyp.googlecode.com/svn/trunk build/gyp
   ```

   (Linking my installed `gyp` to `build/gyp` as suggested in OrangeDog's answer did not work. That's why I did the above.)
5. I ran:

   ```
   $ CXX=g++-4.7 make native
   ```

   Why the `CXX` setting? I ran into a compilation problem right away when I tried with the default gcc. I checked the version. It was 4.8 and I remembered a story on Slashdot about how 4.8 was giving people trouble. So I installed 4.7. Worked fine.
6. I linked `out/native/d8` to a location which is in my `PATH`. This is because the `linux-tick-processor` script does a poor job at finding `d8`. The simplest solution was to make it available in my `PATH`. Your mileage may vary.

After all this, `linux-tick-processor` can be used with the `v8.log` files that Node produces.

Answer (score 0):

Either install the source package - `sudo apt-get source nodejs`, or switch to the [official source](http://nodejs.org/download/) as the ubuntu packages are very out of date.

To build d8, go to the `deps/v8` directory.

1. Create a symlink at `build/gyp` to the directory where `gyp` can be found (e.g. `/usr/bin`).
2. Run `make native`.
3. Copy/symlink `out/native/d8` to somewhere on your PATH.